# Retrive the name of the approver from column A to column B

Tags: custom-list, calculated-column, approval-process, flow

Good day,

My column A ("Was Approved by:") is type "Person or Group" as I need it that way in my flow.
Column B ("Approved by:") can be any type, as I want to make it a calculated field so it doesn't get edited.

I need a way to copy information, from Column A, to Column B, so I can make column A hidden and have Column B, wich can't be edited, showing.

Can someone please help me?!

Thank you!

Comment: You should be able to do this fairly easily with a SharePoint Designer workflow.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this fairly easily with a SharePoint Designer workflow.

Below is a screen shot of how I'd set it up.  May differ slightly depending on how you want your approval to work.  I'm assuming here that the person inputs their name/ID into the Was Approved By field as their approval.  As such, you'd have to first put the value in a workflow variable since you can't check for null on person/name fields.

[image]